# Polymer custom elements: reusing css with import

Tags: javascript, css, html, polymer, web-component

**Problem:**

I cant seem to make the `<i>` tag to render Bootstrap icons, it does not recognize the classes provided by Bootstrap:

**Elements to Diagnose**

tag.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="polymer-tag" attributes="name">
  <template>
    <link rel="import" href="bootstrap.html">

    <style>
      :host { display: block; }
    </style>


    <div>
      <span class="name">{{ name }}</span>

      <!-- This classes are not recognized and the icon is not displayed -->
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>

    </div>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('polymer-tag', {...});

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I have also tried to move the import outside `<polymer-element>` but it does not work either.

`bootstrap.html` contains this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If instead of an import I load a simple old link pointing to `bootstrap.css` then it works, but, If I also use `bootstrap.css` in the Index, the site will load two times `bootstrap.css`

Is this a limitation of Web Components?
Is this an issue of Polymer?

Thanks!

Fran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use an import inside a template today to load CSS scoped to your element, that's known not to work.

Your original idea of using `simple old link pointing to bootstrap.css` is the way to go, the notion is that user agent is supposed to be smart enough to share that CSS.

We consider the double loading you sometimes see today a browser bug. If you can live with it temporarily, that's the way to go. Unfortunately `bootstrap.css` was not written with scoped CSS in mind, so it magnifies this problem more than custom CSS would.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its kind of a bitter sweet answer. Browser are well known to not provide this feature, so I will expect that imports and web components provide this new cability. 

Why this is not implemetend in Polymer? is this a Web Components limitation?

Comment: `Browser are well known to not provide this feature`: 
they do provide this feature, it's just generally not well implemented. We are trying to get that fixed.
`imports and web components provide this new capability`: this is the same answer, 'the platform should do it'.
`Why not implemented in Polymer?`: there are limits to what you can polyfill.
`is this a Web Components limitation`: I don't understand the question. Web Components expects browsers to support style sharing (well). So, it not working well *today* is a browser bug (or todo).

Comment: Nice, now Im very happy with my answer. Thank you very much for your time. I seize the opportunity to thank you all for this great thing that is Polymer!

Comment: Thanks so much for investigation this technology! The newness definitely causes some problems in the early days, so it's very helpful to have people taking a look anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML imports to load external CSS is now supported in **Polymer 1.0** as an experimental feature (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets).

(Haven't tried myself as I haven't upgraded from 0.5 yet :) )